# Custom html tag in Google Tag Manager isn't working

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to make some virtual pageview event for GA using GTM.
I saw some guide how to work with GTM like this one -> http://moz.com/ugc/tracking-google-analytics-events-with-google-tag-manager
I did all steps with only difference  that I'm using analytics.js for GA. A script is listed below:

```
<script>
$("input[name=checkout]").click(function(){
ga('send','pageview','thankspage');
}
)
</script>
```

As a result this custom html tag is not working. I used Google Tag Assistant, but it doesn't see it as well. 
It seems also that all my custom html tags can't be published. I really can't understand what is going wrong with this stuff, because in terms of GTM all things are published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be at least worth a try to change the rules for your custom Tags (you do have rules for them, do you ? Because else  the tags won't fire) from

```
"url contains Regepx .*"
```

(all pages) to

```
event contains gtm.dom
```

That's the tag managers equivalent of jQuery's document.ready and you want to be sure that your input elements actually do exist before you attach events to them (or else you could use jQuery's live()/on() methods) . And of course you must have a GA tag firing before that that actually creates the tracker.

Comment: Good point about gtm.dom! But here are some new details. As I'm firing GA Universal in GTM, I have to use dataLayer and macros to set up pageview method. I also found that I could use predefined GA tag where it is possible to put some macros to "Virtual page path", but for new Universal tag this box doesn't exist.

Comment: You're looking for "document path" in the "More settings/basic" section in the universal analytics tag template.

Answer (score -1):

I also had troubles with custom html tags when tried to append an event to a tag.
Finally I found another way to track virtual pages from tag manager :P:
- first I added a click listener which fire I have controlled with a rule to be sure that will fire only on the desired page
- after that I have created a google analytics tag with the following settings:
       - More Settings -> Basic Configuration -> Virtual Page Path : thankspage(in your case, this will appear in analytics report)
       - as rule I have created a rule that captures the event=gtm.click, element id =your input element id, url = the url on which the click listener fires(you can capture it with contains or regex, whatever you need)